# To convert an html document to a text file in unix?

Tags: unix

Could anyone suggest me any built in function to extract the text from a .html file.  I have tried html2text option but it did'nt work. I have html document as a.html and I need to convert it to pure text file..Any help would be much useful foe me..

Comment: answer please answer please answer please

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lynx ..

```
lynx -dump http://www.subir.com/lynx.html
```

Output

```
                            Lynx source distribution

     * [1]Home page
     * [2]Current development
     * [3]Stable release
     * [4]Mirror sites

   Lynx is the text web browser.

   This is the top level page for the Lynx software distribution site
   hosted by the Internet Software Consortium.
   ....
```

It will work with a file also.